# How to view components outside the JFrame?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jlabel, jscrollbar

I have some JLabels which are not in view on the JFrame. My JFrame has the dimensions: 1366x by 750y. I want to put a few JLabels that are below these dimensions, i.e. at position 800y. It will be a JLabel which has the size 100x by 50y.

I want to have the label already declared and customised from the swing class. But I want to only add it to a `scroll panel` when I press a button. That way, the scroll panel will not scroll until you press the button. This is how it will work:

1. Panel scroll panel which doesn't scroll
2. Button is clicked
3. The label is added to the scroll panel
4. The scroll panel can now scroll. It will scroll because it is set to `ASNEEDED` for the `verticalscrollbarpolicy`.

The problem I have is that I can't see the label when it is under the `JFrame` in the design view of eclipse. Here is a photo:
[image: Screenshot of screen]

How can I do this? Please ask for clarification if required.

**EDIT**

Now If I clicked on some other component above the currently selected label, the eclipse workbench area would scroll up and I wouldn't be able to scroll down to it. To find this label, I would have to find it in the Component Structures list on the left side. I want to be able to scroll the actual workbench area and I want to be able to see the text in that label which is circled.

Comment: Put it in a `JScrollPane` ..

Comment: @AndrewThompson I am not trying to scroll inside the JFrame. The red circle I made above is outside the JFrame. Now If I clicked on some other component above, to find this label, I would have to find it in the Component Structures list on the left side. I want to be able to scroll the actual workbench area and I want to be able to see the text in that label which is circled.